# How are calls to static members of another class handled in Java Object Serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, jvm, static-members, distributed-system

```
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable
{
   public String name = "Tom"; 

   public void mailCheck()
   {
      String address = SomeClass.ItsStaticField(name);  //call to static

      System.out.println("Mailing a check to " + name
                           + " " + address);
   }
}

public class SomeClass()
{         
   // Static Map of <Name, Address>
   private static Map<String, String> NameAddressMap= new HashMap<String, String>();
   string address;

     Static ItsStaticField(name)
       {
          if (NameAddressMap.containsKey(name){
              address = NameAddressMap.get(name);
          }
          else{
            // address =...make a webservice call ... get address for name
            NameAddressMap.put(name, address);
          }
       return address;
       }
}
```

What happens when an object of the above is serialized? And deserialized on another node in a distributed environment? When is 'SomeClass.ItsStaticField()' invoked? Is the 'address' field's value calculated before serialization and then bundled into bytes as part of the serialization process?

Update: Apologize for taking the liberty to add some more info.
Added sample code for 'SomeClass'. 
I have the above code in a distributed environment (specifically Hadoop). I understand this is a bad thing because there are going to be multiple web-service calls, and the intended 'caching mechanism' doesn't really work as expected. What I want to understand is, when and how many times the web-service call would be invoked? And how many instances of the static map 'NameAddressMap' is created on all nodes and when? Thanks much!

Answer (score 4):

> What happens when an object of the above is serialized?

The `name` is serialized

> And deserialized on another node in a distributed environment?

The `name` is deserialized

> When is 'SomeClass.ItsStaticField()' invoked?

When you call `mailCheck();`

> Is the 'address' field's value calculated before serialization and then bundled into bytes as part of the serialization process?

No, it is not a member of the object serialized.

Comment: So when the mailcheck() is called at the deserializing node, it will fail if the dependent 'SomeClass.class' is not already available on it or has not been serialized and sent to it. Right?

Comment: @Gadam how it fails will depend on what is missing. If the class is not installed you will get a ClassNotDefError or similar. If it is installed, the value could be different.  You can create a writeObject() and readObject() method to serialize the value you need to pass, however it would simpler to make the value you need a field.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization serialises the objects fields, not its methods. The contents of the methods remain in the class definition, not in the instance itself.

Answer (score 1):

When a class is serialized, the node deserializing it need all the .class files required for the deserialization. In your case, the class `SomeClass` is part of the dependencies of `Employee`. So, in order to deserialize an Employee, both Employee.class and SomeClass.class are required on the local node.

Note: due to Java being dynamically compiled, it should work until you actually try to call the `mailCheck` method.

Comment: We should make sure SomeClass.class is also available at the deserializing node. In my case, I should hope(and research if) Hadoop Apache Crunch recognizes the dependency on SomeClass.class and serializes that class as well for use at the deserializing node. Am I right?

Comment: The class is not serialized along with the data. Either the client has it already available , or it must be configured to download the class files from some server. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html 
If Apache Crunch deals with sending the class files, then it probably also deals with dependencies.